# Error with Form helper in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: forms, cakephp, authentication

I'm starting out with CakePHP 2.0 and can't get past a simple login. This is my code:

**AppController:**

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'); 
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'hotels', 'action' => 'dashboard');
    }
}
```

**UsersController:**

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Users';
    var $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    var $components = array('Auth','Session');

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Auth->allow("logout");
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    function login()
    {
        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```

**login.ctp:**

```
 echo $this->Form->create(); //'User', array('action' => 'login'));
 echo $form->Form->input('email');
 echo $form->Form->input('password');
 echo $form->Form->end('Login');
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
 Notice (8): Undefined variable: form [APP\View\Users\login.ctp, line 13]
 Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP\View\Users\login.ctp, line 13]
 Fatal error: Call to a member function input() on a non-object in E:\proyectos\web\swt\app\View\Users\login.ctp on line 13
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These

```
echo $form->Form->input('email');
echo $form->Form->input('password');
echo $form->Form->end('Login');
```

should be

```
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

Comment: I've spent like 2 hours going over the same code and didn't see this. Thanks alot! I'm going to kick myself, be right back.

Comment: Just takes a different pair of eyes sometimes. It's those four letter words -- they provoke more four letter words :)

Comment: As a quick follow-up, I've modified my login() method (see above), and I get a form and can submit, but I cannot actually login. It always shows the flash error message and returns me to the form. Any idea? Thanks again

Comment: I haven't set up Auth on 2.0 yet, so all I can suggest is to check your `acos` and `acos_aros` tables. If that doesn't help, you might post a new question.